# how to enable arrow keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application i wrote java script validation for a text field (user name). So it allows only alphabets, spaces, back-space and arrows to move previous and next alphabets in the text field. my code is working fine in the mozila firefox but coming to chrome and IE its not allowing arrow keys.

My code is like this..

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" onkeypress="return isCharacterKey(event)" onkeyup="capitalize(this)" id="firstNameSpaceCapital"/>
```

```
//This function allows space,backspace,alphabets and arrow keys
function isCharacterKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 32 || charCode == 8 || (charCode >= 37 && charCode <= 40) || (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//This method is used to capitalize the first letter in the text field
function capitalize(obj) {
    obj.value = obj.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + obj.value.slice(1);
}

//This method is used to capitalize the first letter after space
$('#firstNameSpaceCapital').on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).val(function (i, val) {
        return val.replace(/(\s)(\S)/g, function ($0, $1, $2) {
            return $1 + $2.toUpperCase();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why are you attaching the events on the html element instead of using the jquery binding you already have?

Comment: using `on*` attributes is a bad practice. Use `addEventListener` and `event.preventDefault()` instead. as @webkit mentioned, use jQuery to do so. `$('#firstNameSpaceCapital').on('keypress'`

Comment: Try use `.bind(` instead of `.on(`

Comment: I used .bind( but no use. I think isCharacterKey(evt) method has not working properly in chrome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd tackle your issue like this:

Notice for the capitalization only css is needed (for the case you presented at least)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eybarta/x5hmx6z6/)

### html

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="firstNameSpaceCapital" />
```

### css

```
.input-lg {text-transform:capitalize;}
```

#### js

```
$('#firstNameSpaceCapital').on('keypress', isCharacterKey);

function isCharacterKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 32 || charCode == 8 || (charCode >= 37 && charCode <= 40) || (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122)) {
        return true;
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
return isCharacterKey(event)
```

`event` is undefined, use `this` instead.

```
return isCharacterKey(this)
```

Comment: if i did this,it shows error "Unexpected token this". The above code is working fine in mozila but not allowing arrow keys in the chrome and IE. Is there any browser compatibility in javascript?

Comment: i don't think so. It is not allowing numbers and other special symbols

Comment: But the input value is undefined, so it cannot validate anything. Check your console.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea to catch keyboard events. 'Cause user can paste some text using mouse. So, I'd recommend to use `oninput` event